# How to access hidden dom element from background window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a button which is present in background window using below jquery but its not working.

I am having a button in my page as below which is hidden by default. But I need to 
show it only when somebody add a records in another pop up. This popup opens in
here in same page. But I am not able to get this button.

```
 <a id="btnAdd" style="display: none;" onclick="Add();" >Add</a>

window.opener.$("#btnAdd").show();
```

Comment: What is a "Popup in the same page"?  How do you open the popup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.opener.$("#btnAdd").show();
```

and Make sure, jquery is also active in new page.

or you can use another approach:

```
var elem = $( "#btnAdd", window.opener.document )
elem.show();
```

In this approach, you don't need to rely on opening window having jQuery.